# Headphone Jack deactive when RasPi starts without screen

Tags: audio, hdmi, screen

I want to set up a Jukebox (Phoniebox) with my RasPi (3b+) with an audio output via the headphone Jack. When I boot the RasPi (3b+) with a connected HDMI screen, everything works fine, and I get an audio output. When I boot without a screen, I can connect to my RasPi with a RFDI-reader, but there is no audio output.
I've already changed the config.txt with

`hdmi_ignore_edid_audio=1`

`audio_pwm_mode=2`

but nothing happens.

Does someone have an idea, what I can change to solve this problem?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Add `dtparam=audio=on` and reboot.

Comment: thanks a lot, but the line was already in the config.txt

Comment: Just to confirm, the “dtparam” line isn’t commented out, is it?

Comment: No, the line isn't commented out

Comment: For me, to comment "hdmi_force_hotplug=1" in "/boot/config.txt" worked